# Open XML in new window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I would like to be able to view xml data using any browser's native xml formatting.  Similar to opening a local xml file in a browser.

1. The xml data is stored as a string which javascript has access to.
2. I do not need anything else on the web page other than the xml data.

   `var xmlString = document.getElementById("xmlDivContent" + name).innerText;`
   `window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8," + xmlString, "", "_blank");`

I've searched around, extensively, for a solution to this problem...I'm not interested in using XSLT or any "home-rolled" formatting function because I just want to take advantage of the browser's built-in xml formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible using the Blob APIs:

```
let blob = new Blob(['<yourxmlstringhere></yourxmlstringhere>'], {type: 'text/xml'});
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
URL.revokeObjectURL(url); //Releases the resources
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be achievable by simply creating a data URL containing the encoded xml information.  Most browsers, notably Chrome, do not support this functionality in a ticket described here: [Intent to Deprecate and Remove: Top-frame navigations to data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B1-25%5D)

In this post they detail the possible alternatives as:

- Generate the file on the backend and send it to the user over http/https.
- Initiate a download instead of displaying the URL.
- If the contents of the URL is trusted, iframe the URL so that the omnibox displays the site's URL.

I ended up downloading the xml.  If someone could come up with a solution for displaying the XML contents in an iframe (using a browser's native xml formatting, that would be a nice improvement)

Comment: How do you dowloaded it?

Comment: @mautrok using javascript.  I placed the xml on the page as plain text in a small (ish) div and used javascript to download that div.InnerText content into a file